Salta la linea 14 de código al colocar en la ejecución más de una palabra en la línea 12
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{

    char rfz[5],descript[60],tllz[2],dzpv[4];
    float cszp, prvzp;
    cout<<"ADMINISTRAR VENTA DE ZAPATOS"<<endl;
    cout<<"Digite la referencia del zapato: "<<endl;
    cin>>rfz;
    cout<<"Digite una descripcion del zapato: "<<endl;
    cin>>descript;
    cout<<"Digite la talla: "<<endl;
    cin>>tllz;
    cout<<"Digite la letra si esta disponible o no para la venta S/M... "<<endl;
    cin>>dzpv;
    cout<<"Digite el costo del zapato: "<<endl;
    cin>>cszp;
    cout<<"Digite el precio de venta del zapato: "<<endl;
    cin>>prvzp;
    
    system("cls");
    cout<<"LOS DATOS REGISTRADOS SON LOS SIGUIENTES   "<<endl;
    cout<<"REFERENCIA:         "<<rfz<<endl;
    cout<<"DESCRIPCION:         "<<descript<<endl;
    cout<<"TALLA:              "<<tllz<<endl;
    cout<<"DISPONIBILIDAD:     "<<dzpv<<endl;
    cout<<"COSTO:              "<<cszp<<endl;
    cout<<"PRECIO DE VENTA:    "<<prvzp<<endl;
    
    cout<<"Gracias por digitar la informacion"<<endl;

system("pause");

return EXIT_SUCCESS;

Me podrían ayudar es que cuando se esta ejecutando y digito la descricpción ejemplo Baleta Roja, omite para digitar la talla y me hace digitar la disponibilidad

Es un problema super-conocido de C/C++ que debería ser parte de de todo curso de estos lenguajes. La cuestión es que el buffer de entrada se satura muy rápido y por eso ya no puede seguir capturando correctamente la entrada. La solución es ir vaciándolo antes de entrar un nuevo valor. Lectura recomendada o también Aca.

Así funciona el operador >> sobre los istream: se descartan los espacios en blanco (espacio, salto de línea, retorno de carro y otros caracteres invisibles) y se extraen todos los caracteres hasta el próximo espacio en blanco.
Por ejemplo, si la entrada es: "Hola, cómo estás?", cin >> descripcion; extraerá "Hola," solamente.
En todo caso, utiliza getline para leer hasta el próximo salto de línea:
// Luego de leer con `>>` queda un salto de línea antes de la línea que quieres leer.
// Hay que quitarlo
cin.ignore(); 
cout<<"Digite una descripcion del zapato: "<<endl;
cin.getline(descript);

O crea tu propia función que se ajuste a tus necesidades. Por ejemplo:
string descripcion;
string palabra;

while ((cin >> palabra) && palabra != "FIN") {
    descripcion += palabra + " ";
}

Extraerá palabras hasta encontrarse con la palabra "FIN" y las concatenará.
Por cierto, es conveniente usar la clase string ya que los arreglos de caracteres no pueden redimensionarse.
